# Excel VBA Recordset not returning all columns from SQL Server View

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Strange issue and not really sure where to begin.

Trying to get SQL Server data into Excel so the user can refresh the query and it'll pull the latest data. I have a View created that links a few tables and smartens up the field names.

I have the VBA to copy from recordset into my sheet, but after the 11th column, it doesn't return anything. Half the fields are missing essentially.

If I amend the query to return ***just*** the column that is missing, it returns about 30 records out of 12,000 and spaced with about 140 cells of blanks (each gap is different) between each record it does return.

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

VBA code here:

```vb
Public Function dbString() As String
dbString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<<SERVERNAME>>;DATABASE=<<DATABASENAME>>;Integrated_Security=SSPI"
End Function

Sub getSQLData_QA()
Dim db As Object
Dim rs As Object

Set db = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set qa = Sheets("QA_Listing")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

db.Open dbString
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = db
        .Open " SELECT * " & _
                " FROM SRV_QBA__13W; "
    End With

    qa.Range("A2:Z100000").Delete xlUp
    qa.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
db.Close

Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any fancy data in one of the columns? Have you tried another driver, eg `dbString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<<Server>>;Initial Catalog = <<Database>>;Integrated Security=SSPI"` ?

Comment: Have you tried to run the same query in SSMS and copy-paste the result into Excel manually?